# Split View in AWS CodeCommit pull request showing unexpected results

Tags: pull-request, aws-codecommit

## Problem Statement

I have a *dev* and *master* branch in AWS CodeCommit. I want to issue a pull request with *master* being the destination and *dev* being the source. When I inspect *StudentCoursework.java* in my *master* branch it shows a multiline comment starting above my `getHoursAttempted()` method and the comment never closes ( so the class will not compile due to syntax error ).

In my *dev* branch the same multiline comment also starts above the  `getHoursAttempted()` method but the comment closes 10 lines later.  However when I look at a pull request in Split View with *master* being the destination and *dev* being the source both sides of the Split View show the multiline comment starting above `getHoursAttempted()` and ending 10 lines later.

I would expect the left side column to be the destination branch ( *master* branch ) and therefore I would expect to see the same syntax error ( never ending comment ) that I see when I inspect the file outside of a pull request.

Please see the following screenshots for clarification.

#### Master Branch

[image: StudentCoursework Master Branch]

#### Dev Branch

[image: StudentCoursework Dev Branch]

#### Split View Configuration

[image: Split View Configuration]

#### Split View Pull Request ( Master <- Dev )

[image: Split View Pull Request]

## Question

As you can see from the last image, when I look at a PR in Split View both columns show the comment starting on 272 and ending on 282.  However In the screenshot of *StudentCoursework.java* taken directly from the *master* branch you can see the comment does not end there.  Am I misunderstanding Split View?  Is the left-hand side of Split View suppose to be the destination branch?

Comment: "split view" is strictly an aws-codecommit feature. It's not generated *by* Git and has little to do with how Git actually sees things. I'll snip off the [tag:git] tag here. (I don't know the AWS-specific answer.)

Comment: As a general rule about Git merges, though, the merge operation goes back to the *shared* commit that's on *both* branches, and figures out what changed by comparing both tip commits against this shared commit. Git's resolution of any merge request involves combining *both* sets of changes, and applying the combined changes to what is in the base commit. The final result of such a merge therefore depends on three inputs, not two; it's not possible to know what it would be without looking at all three. Anything that shows you just two views is lying (perhaps trying to be helpful, but still...).

Comment: This sort of lying-to-hide-complexity often *is* useful and helpful, but in this case it looks like it's hiding something important.

Comment: @torek ahh yes I see.  That is an excellent explanation and exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the info and thanks for fixing my tag.  So that is why when I click on "explore file" in the pull request it goes back to what appeared to be a "random" commit, but really its the most recent commit rev that's shared by both.

Comment: That's probably it, yes. GitHub's pull request web page handling is similar, but different in various ways (not having used the AWS one I can't say *which* ways). GitLab add *their* own wrinkles and Bitbucket add *theirs* and so on. It's kind of a nightmare, if you have to switch between them: I try to stick to command-line Git.

Comment: @torek sorry I realize comments aren't suppose to be chat but just a quick question/clarification.  Are you suggesting to merge dev -> master via the CLI then push a change directly to master instead of doing a pull request?

Comment: That's the way I prefer to use GitHub whenever I'm allowed, yes. Some setups don't allow that. See also any of Linus Torvald's rants about GitHub...